# FluentEmail smtp with authentication - how to configure?

Tags: c#, .net-core, smtp

I can't find a way to configure secure/authenticated smtp when using FluentEmail in Core 2.2.

I've followed this https://lukencode.com/2018/07/01/send-email-in-dotnet-core-with-fluent-email/ which is all understood and where I am at with my code - no problem.

My smtp requires authentication, and without it I cannot send the emails from my app.

How would I go about adding authentication details, e.g. the user name and password?

Has anybody managed to figure this out and able to advise? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FluentEmail is just facade of integrated System.Net.Mail library. Function AddSmtpServer() has overloading including the possibility to pass standard SmtpClient. You can simply construct original SmtpClient and than pass it to the FluentEmail.

```
var client = new SmtpClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("my_user", "my_password");
client.Host = "my_server";
client.Port = 25;

services
    .AddFluentEmail("defaultsender@test.test")              
    .AddSmtpSender(client);
```

The SmtpClient class is marked as obsolete in .Net Core 2.2 and Microsoft recommends another solution ... See below if this may be more fitting.

> "SmtpClient and its network of types are poorly designed, we strongly recommend you use https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit and https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit instead"